# GridView Builder widget in PDF

Tags: flutter, pdf, gridview

I use this library https://pub.dev/packages/pdf to generate a PDF but the widget pw.GridView.builder does not work. The error is : The method 'builder' isn't defined for the type 'GridView'

```
pw.GridView.builder(
                itemCount: photoList.length,
                itemBuilder: (pw.Context context, index) {
                  return pw.Text('');
                }
            ),
```

If it is not managed by this library, what should I do instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package using its own widgets, not Material widgets. The package support `GridView` but, `GridView.builder`.

The `GridView` has a method 'children` wherein You can build children widgets.

Comment: Thank you. It is a good alternative solution.